# How to upload csv file through Protractor

Tags: protractor

I am automating a scenario, need to upload a CSV file and validate the result after uploading the file.

The application code will be as follows:

```
var assetBulkInUploadJson = "./src/resources/scm-test-data/evin/asserts/create-assets-bulk-upload.csv";

var path = require('path');
var assetsTestData = require(path.resolve(assetBulkInUploadJson));
var chooseFileButton= element(by.css("input[file-model='fileData']"));

//send the file address to choose file
chooseFileButton.sendKeys(assetsTestData);
```

I stuck at uploading CSV file, getting the below error

```
  E/launcher - Error: /Users/Sarada/IdeaProjects/scm-ui-automation/src/resources/scm-test-data/evin/asserts/create-assets-bulk-upload.csv:1 (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { //data in csv file displayed

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
at new Script (vm.js:79:7)
at createScript (vm.js:251:10)
at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:303:10)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:28)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
```

If I pass the absolute path directly to the sendKeys() it is working fine.

```
chooseFileButton.sendKeys("/Users/Sarada/IdeaProjects/scm-ui-automation/src/resources/scm-test-data/evin/asserts/create-assets-bulk-upload.csv");
```

How to resolve this issue, how to convert relative path to absolute and send as variable argument? please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with this

```
var assetsTestData = (file) => (path.resolve(__dirname, `${file}`));
```

then

`chooseFileButton.sendKeys(assetsTestData(assetBulkInUploadJson);`

Comment: Hi Joaquin, thanks for your reply. `assetsTestData = (file) => (path.resolve(__dirname, `${file}`));` this line of code is giving the current directory name, but in my code i require project home directory name, is there any possible way to get it? then above code will work

Comment: Thanks, I got the solution, if I remove '__dirname' parameter it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to `require` your file, just specify the path and send it to input

```
var assetBulkInUploadJson = "./src/resources/scm-test-data/evin/asserts/create-assets-bulk-upload.csv";

var path = require('path');
var assetsTestData = path.resolve(__dirname, assetBulkInUploadJson);
var chooseFileButton= element(by.css("input[file-model='fileData']"));

//send the file address to choose file
chooseFileButton.sendKeys(assetsTestData);
```

Comment: Thanks, if I directly use '__dirname' added the called function path to the actual json path, if i remove '__dirname' it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to solve the issue

**Solution 1:**

```
var assetBulkInUploadJson = "./src/resources/scm-test-data/evin/asserts/create-assets-bulk-upload.csv";

var path = require('path');
var assetsTestData = path.resolve(assetBulkInUploadJson);
var chooseFileButton= element(by.css("input[file-model='fileData']"));

//send the file address to choose file
chooseFileButton.sendKeys(assetsTestData);
```

**Solution 2:**

```
var assetBulkInUploadJson = "./src/resources/scm-test-data/evin/asserts/create-assets-bulk-upload.csv";

var path = require('path');
var assetsTestData = (file) => (path.resolve(`${file}`));
var chooseFileButton= element(by.css("input[file-model='fileData']"));

//send the file address to choose file
chooseFileButton.sendKeys(assetsTestData(assetBulkInUploadJson));
```

Thanks @Sergey and @Joaquin